# ¿Como ordenar una lista enlazada genérica?

Tags: java, lista, ordenamiento, enlazado

Alguien que me pueda explicar como ordenar los datos que ingreso o que ya están en la lista Por favor Mi clase Nodo:

public class Nodo {

```
T dato;
Nodo enlace;

public Nodo(T p) {
    dato = p;
    enlace = null;
}
public Nodo(T p, Nodo n) {
    dato = p;
    enlace = n;
}
```

}

Después tengo otra clase llamada lista done tengo estos métodos :

public class Lista {

```
protected Nodo primero, ultimo;
T p;

public Lista() {
    primero = null;
    ultimo = null;
}
public T insertarCabezaLista(T p) {
    primero = new Nodo(p, primero);
    if (ultimo == null) {
        ultimo = primero;
    }
    return null;
}
public void visualizar() {
    Nodo<Integer> n = primero;
    System.out.println();
    while (n != null) {
        System.out.print("[" + n.dato + "]-->");
        n = n.enlace;
    }
}
```

Y por ultimo mi clase prueba:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: Podrias por favor hacer el [tour] asi sabes como funcionamos.. cual es el problema puntual que tuviste?